# How to detailed derivation of multiplicative update rules for Nonnegative Matrix Factorization?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus

How to detailed derivation of multiplicative update rules for Nonnegative Matrix Factorization?

Minimize $\left \| V - WH \right \|^2$ with respect to $W$ and $H$, subject to the constraints $W,H \geq 0.$ The multiplicative update rules are as follows:

\begin{equation}
W_{i,j} \leftarrow W_{ij}   \frac{(VH^T)_{ij}}{(WHH^T)_{ij}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
H_{i,j} \leftarrow H_{ij}  \frac{(W^TV)_{ij}}{(W^TWH)_{ij}}
\end{equation}

the Lagrange $\mathcal{L}$ is:
$$\mathcal{L}(W,H) =\left \| V - WH \right \|^2-Tr(\Psi W^T)-Tr(\Phi H^T)$$

The derivatives with respect to H can computed similarly. Thus,

$$\nabla_W f(W,H) = -2VH^T + 2WHH^T-\Psi$$ 
$$\nabla_H f(W,H) = -2W^TV + 2W^TWH- \Phi$$

According to KKT conditions, $\Psi_{ij}W_{ij}=0$ and $\Phi_{ij}H_{ij}=0$:

$$(-2VH^T + 2WHH^T)\circ W=0$$
$$(-2W^TV + 2W^TWH)\circ H=0$$

> The question is:
>
> Why the results are as follows:
>   \begin{equation}
> W_{i,j} \leftarrow W_{ij}   \frac{(VH^T)_{ij}}{(WHH^T)_{ij}}
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{equation}
> H_{i,j} \leftarrow H_{ij}  \frac{(W^TV)_{ij}}{(W^TWH)_{ij}}
> \end{equation}
>
> Not are as follows:
>   \begin{equation}
> W_{i,j} \leftarrow W_{ij}   \frac{(WHH^T)_{ij} }{(VH^T)_{ij}}
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{equation}
> H_{i,j} \leftarrow H_{ij}  \frac{(W^TWH)_{ij}}{(W^TV)_{ij}}
> \end{equation}

In addition, Why should the learning rate be set like as follows:
$\eta_W = \frac{W}{WHH^T}$ and $\eta_H = \frac{H}{W^TWH}$
Click [here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1861-algorithms-for-non-negative-matrix-factorization.pdf), you can see this paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that near a solution point, the Hadamard fraction is roughly equal to the all-ones matrix
$$\left(\frac{W^TV}{W^TWH}\right) \approx {\tt\large 1}$$
If the elements of $H$ are too big, then the elements of the Hadamard fraction are less than unity (since $H$ appears in the denominator). If they're too small then the fractional elements become greater than unity.

This self-correcting behavior is exactly what is required for a convergent iterative method, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
   H_+ = H \odot\left(\frac{W^TV}{W^TWH}\right) \\
}$$
On the other hand, the reciprocal fraction
$$\left(\frac{W^TWH}{W^TV}\right) \approx {\tt\large 1}$$
has the opposite behavior, i.e. large elements in $H$ produce a Hadamard fraction with elements greater than unity, leading to even larger elements in $H$ in the next iteration, and eventually to divergence.

Answer (score 1):

The detailed derivation of multiplicative update rules is given here [derivationMU](https://www.jjburred.com/research/pdf/jjburred_nmf_updates.pdf)